# convergence in distriubtion of $(\max_{1\leq k\leq n} X_k)/ln(n)$ where $X_k\sim \text{Exp}(1)$.

Tags: probability

The problem is: Let $X_k$'s be i.i.d. $\text{Exp}(1)$ r.v.'s. define:
$$\xi_n = max_{1\leq k\leq n} X_k$$
$$\eta_n = \xi_n/ln(n)$$.
The question is what is the limit of $\eta_n$ as $n\to \infty$?

Here is my approach:
$$P(\xi_n\leq x) = P(\max_{1\leq k\leq n}X_k\leq x) = \prod_{k=1}^{n}(1-e^{-x}) = (1-e^{-x})^n$$
$$P(\eta_n\leq x) = P(\frac{\xi_{n}}{ln(n)}\leq x) = P(\xi_n\leq ln(n) x) = (1-e^{-ln(n) x})^n = (1-\frac{1}{n^x})^n$$

What is the limit of $(1-e^{-ln(n) x})^n$ as $n\to \infty$?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the limit of $(1-e^{-ln(n) x})^n$ as $n\to \infty$?

Hint: Let $x_n=(1-a_n)^n$ with $a_n$ in $(0,1)$ for every $n$.

- If $na_n\to\alpha$ with $\alpha$ in $(0,+\infty)$ then $x_n\to\mathrm e^{-\alpha}$
- If $na_n\to0$ then $x_n\to1$
- If $na_n\to\infty$ then $x_n\to0$

In your case, you know that $(1-e^{-\ln(n) x})^n=(1-1/n^x)^n$ hence $a_n=1/n^x$. The result follows.

Comment: Do you know where the mistake in my deleted answer is? In case you can't recover it, that's what I wrote: *It is known that $\xi_n - \log(n)$ converges in law to the Gumbel distribution. Thus, $\xi_n/\log(n)$ = $(\xi_n-log(n))/\log(n) + 1$ converges in law to $0+1=1$.* Apparently the reasoning that if $X_n$ converges in distribution t $X$ and $Y_n$ converges in distribution to a constant $c$, then $X_n Y_n$ converges in distribution to $cX$ is wrong. If it takes too long to answer here, I'll open a new question.

Comment: @herrsimon Everything is (was) correct in your post, including the conclusion (and I can see deleted posts).

Comment: Ok, then I'm concluding wrong things from your answer, but I've been doing too much mathematics today anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is known that $\xi_n - \log(n)$ converges in law to the Gumbel distribution. Thus, $\xi_n/\log(n)$ = $(\xi_n-log(n))/\log(n) + 1$ converges in law to $0+1=1$.